# Angled margin for text using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a simple and elegant way to dynamically increase the right margin for an HTML text area (div) using css like the following with a configurable degree (say 45 degrees to start with).

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,/
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore   /
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud   /
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea   /  
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in         /
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore/ 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat /
```

The slashes schematically represent the margin increasing with each text line.

Comment: Have a look at this :) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Comment: It's nice and probably the preferred way, but it doesn't seem to work in my browser (tried both Chrome 46.0.2490.86 and Safari 9.0.1 on my mac)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) ([generator](http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator)) for that, but it's support is very poor.

Other way would be to calculate how mush symbols you can have per-line.

E.g. if 1 letter is ~10px, than **(not tested)**:

```
[php]
$letters = explode('', $text);
$letterSize = 10;
$startingLength = 120;
$textGrid = [];
$row = 0;
$rowLength = 0;

while (!empty($letters)) {
   if (!isset($textGrid[$row])) {
       $textGrid[$row] = [];
   }

   $textGrid[$row][] = array_pop($letters);

   $rowLength++;

   if ($rowLength >= $startingLength / $letterSize) {
       $startingLength -= $letterSize; // experiment here for 45 angle.
       $rowLength = 0;
       $row++;
   }
}

foreach ($textGrid as $row) {
    echo '<span>';
    foreach ($row as $letter) {
        echo $letter;
    }
    echo '</span>';
}
```

Comment: `clip-path`  works in new browsers. This is better answer than the others that only works in chrome desktop. Upvote to you

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using `float:right`
http://jsfiddle.net/t8pgkdp8/3/

You can generate these styles with any css preprocessor or javascript

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [**CSS Shapes Module Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes/). In particular at the [**shape-outside**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes/#shape-outside-property) property, which will let you change the geometry of floated elements, but be aware that it has the status of "Candidate Recommendation" and most likely will not work in **FF** or **IE** at the moment.

[**Can I use shape-outside**](http://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside)

Here is a polyfill for none supported browsers [**shapes-polyfill**](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill)

The following example will add an element with class of `shape` to the main container, if the `-webkit-shape-outside` property is supported.

```js
if('-webkit-shape-outside' in document.body.style) {
  $('.main').prepend('<div class="shape">');
}
```

```css
.main {
  width: 475px;
  height: 200px;
}

.shape {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(45% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(45% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 22ex;
  background-color: gray;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(45% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(45% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);

}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <p>
    Sometimes a web page's text content appears to be
    funneling your attention towards a spot on the page
    to drive you to follow a particular link.  Sometimes
    you don't notice. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod nam itaque, adipisci odit, quaerat veniam ea. Accusamus fugit mollitia blanditiis voluptas maiores, quas quisquam earum consequuntur explicabo repudiandae. Possimus, sit.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution myself which is mentioned here: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

Basically it amounts to setting borders with increasing width like the following:

```
<div style="border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px;float:right;clear:right; margin-right: 50px"></div>
<div style="border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 20px;float:right;clear:right; margin-right: 50px"></div>
<div style="border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 40px;float:right;clear:right; margin-right: 50px"></div>
<div style="border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 60px;float:right;clear:right; margin-right: 50px"></div>
<p>Some text here that will wrap with the angled border</p>
```

It's rather uggly but it does work. Open for a better solution though.